# Why can I not set my Tempomat (cruise-control) to a speed below 30km/h?

Tags: cruise-control, speedometer

Why is it impossible to set a speed below 30 km/h on every Tempomat I've ever seen? Is it for legal reasons or technical difficulties with low speeds?

It would be helpful in a stop and go situation.

Comment: They are designed that way.

Comment: It's a safety consideration mostly. Your car can reach 30km/h pretty quickly + it's faster than it feels. You could have an accident or injure someone if you press the Resume button and you go flying forward.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Generally a 30 zone implies you are in town, where you are subject to children, pets, footballs, stopping traffic etc.

Cruise control is for long distances at a constant speed where you are not subject to rapidly changing risks - not for stop-go situations. In town you should be concentrating on what is going on and adjusting your speed constantly based on what is around you.

Specifically to your final sentence - **Cruise control is the opposite of what you want in a stop go situation!**